# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol/

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors, lnk2019

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to compile an ogre sample found on Github.

I've had several Intellisense errors, compilation & linking errors. Now I'm stuck with 2 linker errors. I know there's a lot of similar questions around here because I've read a lot on the subject but I can't find (or see) the right solution.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall NFSpace::PlanetMapTile::PlanetMapTile(struct NFSpace::QuadTreeNode *,class Ogre::SharedPtr<class Ogre::Texture>,class Ogre::Image,class Ogre::SharedPtr<class Ogre::Texture>,int)" (??0PlanetMapTile@NFSpace@@QAE@PAUQuadTreeNode@1@V?$SharedPtr@VTexture@Ogre@@@Ogre@@VImage@4@1H@Z) referenced in function "public: class NFSpace::PlanetMapTile * __thiscall NFSpace::PlanetMap::finalizeTile(struct NFSpace::QuadTreeNode *)" (?finalizeTile@PlanetMap@NFSpace@@QAEPAVPlanetMapTile@2@PAUQuadTreeNode@2@@Z)  

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: struct NFSpace::QuadTreeNode const * __thiscall NFSpace::PlanetMapTile::getNode(void)" (?getNode@PlanetMapTile@NFSpace@@QAEPBUQuadTreeNode@2@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall NFSpace::PlanetRenderable::setFrameOfReference(struct NFSpace::PlanetLODConfiguration &)" (?setFrameOfReference@PlanetRenderable@NFSpace@@QAEXAAUPlanetLODConfiguration@2@@Z)
```

---

here is the code associated with the first error:

**PlanetMapTile.h**

```
namespace NFSpace {

class PlanetMapTile {  

public:
PlanetMapTile(QuadTreeNode* node, TexturePtr heightTexture, Image heightImage, TexturePtr normalTexture, int size);
~PlanetMapTile();
};
}
```

**PlanetMapTile.cpp**

```
#include "PlanetMapTile.h"

namespace NFSpace {

PlanetMapTile::PlanetMapTile(QuadTreeNode* node, TexturePtr heightTexture, Image heightImage, TexturePtr normalTexture, int size) {     
//do something
}

PlanetMapTile::~PlanetMapTile() {
//do something
}
}
```

**PlanetMap.h**

```
#include "PlanetMapTile.h"  

namespace NFSpace {

class PlanetMap {
public:
PlanetMapTile* finalizeTile(QuadTreeNode* node);  
};
}
```

**PlanetMap.cpp**

```
 #include "PlanetMap.h"

 namespace NFSpace {

 PlanetMapTile* PlanetMap::finalizeTile(QuadTreeNode* node) {
    mStep = 0;
    return new PlanetMapTile(node, mHeightTexture, mHeightImage, mNormalTexture, getInt("planet.textureSize"));
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is PlanetMapTile.cpp getting compiled?

Comment: Also, where is getNode declared/defined?

Comment: Is your class, declared in `PlaneTitleMap.h` inside your `NFSpace` namespace?

Comment: @ Luchian Grigore Yes I have all the obj files right. The problems arise whith the linker

Comment: This code doesn't compile. `namespace NFSpace` is missing a closing brace, and `class PlanetMap` is missing a closing semicolon.

Comment: @TonyK I'm sorry this is just a typo in the question

Comment: Afaict `TexturePtr` should not have been translated to its base class `Ogre::SharedPtr<class Ogre::Texture>`.  Hard to guess how that happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally found the solution:

Considering the fact that `PlanetMapTile()` and `getNode()` were both involving `QuadTreeNode*` and that `~PlanetMapTile()` didn't raise an error, I've started to look at the `QuadTreeNode` declaration which is located in **PlanetCubeTree.h**. Then I've just tried to add `#include "PlanetCubeTree.h"` to **PlanetMapTile.h** and it solved the error.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

That is how you should declare the name space

**PlanetMApTile.h**

```
namespace NFSpace{
class PlanetMapTile {  

public:
PlanetMapTile(QuadTreeNode* node, TexturePtr heightTexture, Image heightImage, TexturePtr normalTexture, int size);
~PlanetMapTile();
};  
}
```

**PlanetMapTile.cpp**

```
#include "PlanetMapTile.h"
NFSpace::PlanetMapTile::PlanetMapTile(QuadTreeNode* node, TexturePtr heightTexture, Image heightImage, TexturePtr normalTexture, int size) {     
//do something
}

NFSpace::PlanetMapTile::~PlanetMapTile() {
//do something
}
```

**PlanetMap.h**

```
#include "PlanetMapTile.h"  

class PlanetMap {
public:
NFSpace::PlanetMapTile* finalizeTile(QuadTreeNode* node);  
}
```

**PlanetMap.cpp**

```
#include "PlanetMap.h"

NFSpace::PlanetMapTile* PlanetMap::finalizeTile(QuadTreeNode* node) {
    mStep = 0;
    return new NFSpace::PlanetMapTile(node, mHeightTexture, mHeightImage, mNormalTexture, getInt("planet.textureSize"));
}
```

Comment: It's completely OK, to have a `using` statement, or wrap the function definitions inside a `namespace` block in the translation unit.

Comment: forgot to add the `namespace NFSpace` in my question but it's there in **PlanetMApTile.h**. I'll try `NFSpace::PlanetMapTile::PlanetMapTile`

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ of course you could use "using" I tend not to use it as i like to be explicit when coding

Comment: @GeorgesS. could you be more specific ? In my opinion it should work like this just fine

Comment: @thebaconing I'm trying what you suggest but I still get the error

Comment: @GeorgesS. Well it should work like this. as  Hans Passant mentioned in the comments it is suspicious that the types get converted. I don't know how your project setup looks like or if you are really using the correct files. Thats what i would check if i were you

Comment: @thebaconing There's `using namespace Ogre` in both header files, could it be related ? I really don't know what's left to check

Comment: @GeorgesS. that shouldn't make any difference. Is the compiler warning still the same after you applied my suggestion?

Comment: @thebaconing the message is the same.